# Changing the default admin path

Tags: admin, 404

I am trying to reset the default path to the dashboard from admin to something else. I have this in `config/general.php`:

```
return array(
    'cpTrigger' => 'new-url',
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
    'devMode' => true,
);
```

But when I go to `devsite.myurl.co.uk/new-url`, I get a 404 error. I got this working locally but not since I installed the site on a staging server, and imported the database and changed the general and db files. Any ideas?

If I take out the `cpTrigger` line, and just use `devsite.myurl.co.uk/admin`, everything is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Have you got your `htaccess` file working ok? By default the `htaccess` file is named incorrectly, it should be `.htaccess not`htaccess`. You can read about renaming that file in the [installation docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/installing#step-1-upload-the-files).

As a quick test you could try:
"/index.php/new-url"

If that works it's your `htaccess` file.